# How to add SQLite manage in FireFox

Tags: sqlite, firefox-addon

I remove Sqlite manager by mistake from my add-ons.

Now i can't add and this message is displayed: "This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox.".

What can i do.

Comment: Hello. This question seems to be best suited for the folks at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a non-browser based SQLite Tool e.g. :-

- [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)
- [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)
- [Navicat (trial version is free but only for 14 days)](https://www.navicat.com/en/download/navicat-premium?gclid=Cj0KCQjw5-TXBRCHARIsANLixNwTgGZyb7LTcmvi5wpWNH04kQpUMxafKkexyD5fY5tFXdcfLWxWRIQaAnrOEALw_wcB)
- [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt)

You could try using Pale Moon (Firefox based, but without the new extension manager).

You could try Firefox Extended Support Release. [Mozilla Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/)

Perhaps have a look at [SQLite Manager and new Firefox](https://github.com/datacarpentry/sql-ecology-lesson/issues/199)